# The ellipse is outlined, how to fill?

Tags: matlab, fill, ellipse

In this [tutorial](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/07/30/visualizing-regionprops-ellipse-measurements/), an `ellipse` will be outlined. As you can see, a red border will be drawn around. Form such result, how can we fill such surrounded border with `white`, and the rest of the image as `black`?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to include the relevant information in the question itself, and not only as a link. This makes it easier to help you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little Google search with the words fill and Matlab would tell you that there is a function called fill which performs what you want(check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html?refresh=true)).

In the example, putting it right after the call to plot gives something like the following. I put the whole code for the for-loop:

```
for k = 1:length(s)
xbar = s(k).Centroid(1);
ybar = s(k).Centroid(2);

a = s(k).MajorAxisLength/2;
b = s(k).MinorAxisLength/2;

theta = pi*s(k).Orientation/180;
R = [ cos(theta)   sin(theta)
     -sin(theta)   cos(theta)];

xy = [a*cosphi; b*sinphi];
xy = R*xy;

x = xy(1,:) + xbar;
y = xy(2,:) + ybar;

plot(x,y,'r','LineWidth',2);

fill(x,y,rand(1,3)) %// Here is the important line.
end
```

[image]

I'll let you discover how you can fill the ellipses with white instead of random colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer. Yes, this does it. I'll see how I can fill it with white

Comment: great then. Please ask if you can't find out. Oh and if the answer helped you can you mark it as accepted please? (click the green tick mark) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I figured how to make the ellipse `white`. Instead of the `rand(1,3)` part, we add `[1 1 1]`. Thanks for your kind support

Comment: yep that's it! You can also use strings to refer to colors, such as 'w', 'k', 'b' etc. Glad you found out!